# Promise.finally is not defined in Electron with Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a so weird problem that I don't have an idea where to search for the error.
The error I found is:

```
myFunction().finally is not a function
```

where myFunction return a `return (new ApolloClient({link, cache})).query()`.

The weird stuff is that it works on Chrome but not on Electron.

The code is compiled using Webpack 4 and the following JS Loaders:

```
let jsLoaders = [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: [
            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
            'angularjs-annotate',
        ].concat(isDevelopment ? ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'] : []),
    },
}];
```

but even trying the update the babel presets with

```
presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
            useBuiltIns: "usage",
            shippedProposals: true,
            corejs: "3.9.1",
        }]],
```

it works on Chrome but not Electron.

Another esoteric behaviour is that, using Electron, if I navigate to another specific page (discovered clicking around in the app), totally uncorrelated with the broken page, the broken page results fixed and start to find `finally` as a function...

Comment: I suspect you're not getting a vanilla promise object but different one. You can convert and use it with `Promise.resolve( myFunction() ).finally()` assuming you still have vanilla promises areound. However it might be good to look into why are is there a difference promise implementation used because whatever it is, it might be overriding the global `Promise`. If you say that navigating makes `.finally` work, then I suspect that a promise library might be taking over in some cases. When it "works" are the instances the competing promise implementation is not loaded.

Comment: Even trying to execute `Promise.resolve().finally(() =>. {})` in the code, it works in the same way described below, i.e. broken first time, fixed after visited that "magic" page

Comment: In that case, it's a problem with the global `Promise`. Visiting the "magic" page must be doing or **not** doing something with it. It's hard to say.

Comment: The magic page is just a standard page. I think it is something related to babel and maybe in the page there is a chunk produced by Webpack that does the magic... ?